# Read and write using DocumentMetadataHandle and InputStreamHandle

Tags: marklogic

Trying to read a document from one location and write to a different location. Using DocumentMetadataHandle to get metadata and InputStreamHandle to read content. For write when i use the same InputStreamHandle which i used for read throwing stream closed exception. The same is not happening when i don't use DocumentMetadataHandle in read. Code a below. Using Java Client API 3.0.7

```
XMLDocumentManager documentManager = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
Transaction transaction = client.openTransaction();
InputStreamHandle handle = new InputStreamHandle();
DocumentMetadataHandle metadataHandle = new DocumentMetadataHandle();
documentManager.read(uri, metadataHandle, handle,transaction);
documentManager.write(newUri, metadataHandle, handle, transaction);
```

Comment: Thanks, Siju, I believe you've found a bug.  Erik's solution should provide you with a work-around.  However, I've logged this in github so we can address it: https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/783

Comment: Erik's SOlution ?

Comment: The post by ehennum, below, that suggests using BytesHandle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to buffer the document in memory for writing back to the server, you might consider using BytesHandle instead of an InputStreamHandle.

DocumentMetadataHandle does buffer the metadata.